# What are the most popular extensions for CiviCRM?

Tags: extension, developer

Ever wonder how many Civi sites are using a particular extension? Which are the popular extensions your site is not yet using? Me too!

Answer (score 4):

Here's the answer - the most popular extensions for CiviCRM ranking numbers are here: https://stats.civicrm.org/?tab=sites